# If varA==NA, how do I impute NA row-wise to all variables whose names start with varA?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, purrr, na

I am trying to revise an eligible sample size for a number of 'check all that apply' questions by recoding all `0`'s in `df` to `NA` if NONE of the options were selected. I have created a character vector that comprises all of the 'check all that apply' fields (`check_all`) by collapsing the *root* or prefix of each field. I then calculated a row-wise sum across each field--if `>0` then at least one response was selected. Finally I recoded these variables to `NA` if the sum was `0` ...

```
df_test <- check_all %>% # character vector in which every element is a prefix of 2+ variables in df
map_dfc(~ df %>% select(contains(.x)) %>% reduce(~ ..1 + ..2)) %>% # select vars in df and sum based on partial matching of elements in 'check_all'
set_names(., check_all) %>% # rename based on character vector
mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(.,0))) %>% # recode 0 to NA
```

but now I don't know how to conditionally select all matching variables in `df` and recode to `NA` if its prefix counterpart (in `df_test`) is `NA`.

The structure of `df_test` is:

```
> dput(head(df_test))
structure(list(varA = c(NA, 3, 5, NA, 7, NA), varB = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), varC = c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 5, 
NA), varD = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), varE = c(NA, 
1, NA, NA, 1, NA), varF = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA), varG = c(NA, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA), varH = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and an example of what `df` looks like is:

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(varA___1=c(0,3,5,0,7,0),
varB___1=c(0,0,0,0,1,0), varC___1=c(0,1,2,0,5,0),
varD___1=c(0,1,0,0,0,0), varE___1=c(0,1,0,0,1,0),
varF___1=c(0,1,1,0,1,0), varG___1=c(0,1,1,0,0,0),
varH___1=c(0,1,1,0,1,0), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Where `varA:varH` are the prefixes; all variants of these found in `df` can be captured by suffixing the prefix with "`___[0-9]`"

I really don't want to have to go through `df` and conditionally subset it, based on the elements in `check_all`, one-by-one, but I know I *could* do it that way. Is there a more programmatic approach?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could include a sample dataframe - use dput(df_test) or dput(head(df_test))

Comment: This is definitely something that can be done, but as @Mark notes, if we can see the structure of your data frame it will make it much easier to give you a workable solution.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the structure of the dataframe